# SQL: Can a single OVER clause support multiple window functions?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Let's say I've got a list of pageview events, each of which has a session id. For each event I want to add the time and URL of the chronologically first pageview in that event's session.  For example, lets say my events are in table `test` which looks like this:

```
uid | session_id | timestamp | url
----------------------------------------------------
u1    0            0           a.com/
u1    1            1           a.com/p1
u1    1            2           a.com/p2
```

I want a SQL command that produces the following:

```
uid | session_id | timestamp | url      | s_timestamp | s_url
---------------------------------------------------------------------
u1    0            0           a.com/     0             a.com/
u1    1            1           a.com/p1   1             a.com/p1
u1    1            2           a.com/p2   1             a.com/p1
```

Window functions seem to be the way to go here, but I'm pretty new to them.  The following statement produces the desired table, but I'm wondering if it's suboptimal

```
SELECT
    uid,
    session_id,
    timestamp,
    url,
    first_value(url) OVER (PARTITION BY uid, session_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) s_url,
    first_value(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY uid, session_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) s_timestamp
FROM test
```

In particular, it seems wrong that I use the `OVER` clause twice.  Is there a way to select the chronologically first URL and timestamp from a session using a single OVER clause?  I'm using SPARK SQL, but I will accept any answer that is applicable to multiple major SQL systems.

Comment: Yes, you can introduce a name for a window using the WINDOW keyword, and reference that name multiple times using OVER. (I don't know if apache spark-sql implements this, though)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just tried using a window function as specified in the hive sql reference, and it works.  You should write up the answer--if you don't want to, then I can do it (but you earned it).

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to use the `WINDOW` keyword to name a window that can then be references in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT
    uid,
    session_id,
    timestamp,
    url,
    first_value(url) OVER w s_url,
    first_value(timestamp) OVER w s_timestamp
FROM test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY uid, session_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC)
```

This works in Apache Spark SQL and HiveQL.

Comment: Thanks joop for the tip.

Comment: If you also have a `WHERE` clause then make sure to put it *before* the `WINDOW` clause.